# Guice: is it possible to inject modules?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a `Module` that requires some arbitrary `Depedency`.  Is there a way Modules themselves can be injected?  I realize this is a bit of a chicken and egg situation...

Example:

```
public class MyModule implements Module {

    private final Dependency d;

    @Inject public MyModule(Dependency d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void configure(Binder b) { }

    @Provides Something provideSomething() {
        return new SomethingImpl(d);
    }
}
```

I suppose in this case the solution would be to turn the `@Provides` method into a full-fledged `Provider<Something>` class.  This is clearly a simplified example; the code I'm dealing with has many such `@Provides` methods so cutting them each into individual `Provider<...>` classes and introducing a module to configure them adds a fair amount of clutter - and I thought Guice was all about reducing boilerplate?

Perhaps it's a reflection of my relative noobyness to Guice but I've come across a fair few cases where I've been tempted to do the above.  I must be missing something...

Comment: You suggest that your example is simplified - perhaps showing a more detailed example would inspire a better response?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`@Provides` methods can take dependencies as parameters just like parameters to an `@Inject` annotated constructor or method:

```
@Provides Something provideSomething(Dependency d) {
   return new Something(d); // or whatever
}
```

This is documented [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods), though perhaps it could be made to stand out more.

Comment: Thanks Colin and you're right, I overlooked the official doc, which is actually very clear if a little too concise (normally a very good thing).  Lesson learned (study the official doc more closely) but hopefully a useful thing to call out for others too!

Comment: I know I'm asking for a lot here but now I've found about this feature (and boy, is it handy!), it would be delightful if it could be combined with the `@Nullable` annotation.  eg: in the above example, this would make `Dependency` an optional binding.  Alas, this doesn't seem to work (Guice 2.0 complains that "No Implementation for Dependency was bound").  Wondering if this could be a feature of a forthcoming version of Guice or maybe there's a good reason not to have this?

Comment: @Christian: `@Nullable` doesn't make dependencies optional, it allows `null` to be bound using `toProvider(Providers.<Dependency>of(null))`. Don't know that there's any way to make a specific dependency to an `@Provides` method optional.

Comment: Many thanks Colin, I see have a few things to learn about Guice ;-)

Comment: This solved my inter-dependency issue as well. I think it should definitely be made more clear that you can use it like this, on the wiki.

Answer (score 13):

Using a provider or @Provides methods are great if you need a dependency to manually construct an object. However, what if you need something to help you decide how to configure the bindings themselves? It turns out you can use Guice to create (and configure) your module.

Here is a (contrived) example.  First, the module we want to configure:

```
/**
 * Creates a binding for a Set<String> which represents the food in a pantry.
 */
public class PantryModule extends AbstractModule {
  private final boolean addCheese;

  @Inject
  public ConditionalModule(@Named("addCheese") boolean addCheese) {
    this.addCheese = addCheese;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    Multibinder<String> pantryBinder = Multibinder
      .newSetBinder(binder(), String.class);

    pantryBinder.addBinding().toInstance("milk");

    if (addCheese) {
      pantryBinder.addBinding().toInstance("cheese");
    }

    pantryBinder.addBinding().toInstance("bread");
  }
}
```

The PantryModule expects a boolean value to be injected to decide whether or not it should include cheese in the pantry.

Next, we'll use Guice to configure the module:

```
// Here we use an anonymous class as the "configuring" module. In real life, you would 
// probably use a standalone module.
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // No cheese please!
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("addCheese")).to(false);
    bind(PantryModule.class);
  }
});

Module configuredConditionalModule = injector.getInstance(PantryModule.class);
```

Now that we have a configured module, we'll update our injector to use it...

```
//...continued from last snippet...
injector = injector.createChildInjector(configuredConditionalModule);
```

And finally we'll get the set of strings that represent our pantry:

```
//...continued from last snippet...
Set<String> pantry = injector.getInstance(new Key<Set<String>>() {});

for (String food : pantry) {
  System.out.println(food);
}
```

If you put all the pieces together in a main method and run it, you'll get the following output:

```
milk
bread
```

If you change the binding to the "addCheese" boolean to true, you'll get:

```
milk
cheese
bread
```

This technique is cool, but probably only useful when you have control over the Injector instance and only when the module requires complex dependencies. Nonethless, I found a real need for this on a real project at work. If I did, then someone else might too.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, and I thought I could be going crazy.. I feel better now, I know that I'm not alone ;)

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't just use field injection for the boolean?

Answer (score 5):

The question is already well answered, but I just wanted to add a variation to Colin's example:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule { 
  public void configure() {
    bind(Something.class).toProvider(new Provider<Something>() {
       @Inject Dependency d;
       Something get() { return d.buildSomething(); }
    }
  }
}
```

The @Provides method approach is clearer than what I have above for this simple case, but I've found that instantiating an actual Provider can be useful in some situations too.  Something I stole from the mailing list; wouldn't have occurred to me on my own ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with initializing the module just by calling `new MyModule(d)` or by creating a `Provider<Something>` that has an injected `Injector`?  Those would appear to be the standard ways of handling this sort of problem.  As has been mentioned, you can also use `@Provides` methods with arguments.

If the dependency is optional then you can create the module and then call a setter to initialize the value if needed (e.g.,  `com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule` does this with properties, while using `new JpaPersistModule(String)` to load the correct configuration).

Otherwise I suppose it might be possible to do so (and then call `createChildInjector(Modules... modules)`), but I'd almost always prefer one of the other approaches to that one.

Comment: Thanks dclements.  The issue with `new MyModule(d)` is that this wouldn't use DI, right?  On (2), I'm no big fan of setter injection (though I understand that it's can be a necessary evil).  As for the last suggestion, this looks like a useful advanced technique that I wasn't aware of.  However, it has to be said that the auto-injected parametrized `@Provides` method is indeed a very elegant solution that I wasn't aware of...